# Debug disassembled code

Tags: assembly, low-level

How Can I debug this disassembled code? I have to rewrite this function on C++ language. But at first I must understand how it works.

There is any way to debug it?

```
0804865a <generate_key>:
 804865a:    55                       push   %ebp
 804865b:    89 e5                    mov    %esp,%ebp
 804865d:    57                       push   %edi
 804865e:    56                       push   %esi
 804865f:    53                       push   %ebx
 8048660:    83 ec 18                 sub    $0x18,%esp
 8048663:    8b 7d 0c                 mov    0xc(%ebp),%edi
 8048666:    ff 75 08                 pushl  0x8(%ebp)
 8048669:    e8 b2 fe ff ff           call   8048520 <atoi@plt>
 804866e:    83 c4 10                 add    $0x10,%esp
 8048671:    85 c0                    test   %eax,%eax
 8048673:    89 c3                    mov    %eax,%ebx
 8048675:    75 0f                    jne    8048686 <generate_key+0x2c>
 8048677:    e8 d4 fe ff ff           call   8048550 <rand@plt>
 804867c:    b9 40 42 0f 00           mov    $0xf4240,%ecx
 8048681:    99                       cltd   
 8048682:    f7 f9                    idiv   %ecx
 8048684:    89 d3                    mov    %edx,%ebx
 8048686:    31 c9                    xor    %ecx,%ecx
 8048688:    be 1b 00 00 00           mov    $0x1b,%esi
 804868d:    eb 13                    jmp    80486a2 <generate_key+0x48>
 804868f:    8d 04 c9                 lea    (%ecx,%ecx,8),%eax
 8048692:    31 d2                    xor    %edx,%edx
 8048694:    01 d8                    add    %ebx,%eax
 8048696:    f7 f6                    div    %esi
 8048698:    8a 82 18 9e 04 08        mov    0x8049e18(%edx),%al
 804869e:    88 04 0f                 mov    %al,(%edi,%ecx,1)
 80486a1:    41                       inc    %ecx
 80486a2:    3b 4d 10                 cmp    0x10(%ebp),%ecx
 80486a5:    73 05                    jae    80486ac <generate_key+0x52>
```

Comment: Simple, reassemble it.

Comment: there is any windows program?

Comment: The best way to do it is to a) learn assembly language and then to b) reverse engineer it back to C or C++ code.  Clearly this is far too broad for a question here.

Comment: A quick glance says that you are trying to reverse engineer a numeric key and, likely, craft a key generator for it.

Comment: But it is assembler not C/C++ so I can reverse it back to C?

Comment: Of course you can.  You can learn assembly, understand what it's doing and rewrite it in any language that you want to.

Comment: That's not a complete function.  It has no RET instruction, and no tailcall jump outside itself either.  Either it's super-weird and the JAE at the bottom is actually always taken, or there's more code there which you forgot to look at.

Comment: BTW, this is missing some code (even those `call` may be non-standard), so you can't be 100% sure what this code does. If you have source of this (original binary), than you can produce larger disassembly, with all code included, then it will be possible to decipher what it does. But if you have the binary, why would you want to write it in C++, if you already have functional code (maybe just hack some code to call it in a way as you need it, but you can still abuse the original binary for the "meat" of it).

Comment: @PeterCordes This function *is* incomplete, but not because it's missing a `retq` (TCO could have caused it). I see no code to restore callee-save registers, and the JAE suggests there's something below, as you pointed out.

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist: I *did* mention tailcalls.  Good point, I didn't look for a register-restoring epilogue, just RET or J*.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Yup, that's exactly what I thought, too.  I only commented that way to point out that it was possible. :P  BTW, I wish gcc was smart enough to use `jcc` as a tailcall, but it isn't. :(  (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69576) and (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42497#c3).

Comment: @PeterCordes Wow, what a fun optimization that could be for a graduate class in compilers!

Answer (score 1):

You may:

A) use that part on right (instruction mnemonics) with some assembler like gas (your listing is in AT&T syntax, so gas is natural choice) to compile it (it may require some syntax fixes to be compilable, and set up correctly things like code segment and starting point, etc). Advantage is, that you can also include your own helper instructions to modify the code, if you are interested into something (if you know Assembly good enough to program in it).

B) take the middle part of byte code values, and simply write that in hexa editor into file... then load that into debugger into memory to code segment, set `cs:eip` at the beginning and there you go. Advantage of this approach is that you don't need to fix any syntax, hexa bytes values are hexa bytes values.

Both approaches have one huge pitfall, things like `call   8048520 <atoi@plt>` will not call the desired code, as it's not part of your listing, nor you will hardly make it to start at the same physical address, as that listing was taken from, so again you have to understand Assembly to fully understand how to adjust any global pointer value in that code, and also remove those `calls` and instead simulate their function by modification of registers/memory in that spot by hand in debugger (so you have to fully understand what those call originally did).

But usually when these exercises are given, the binary is available, so students can run it in debugger on their own, so I wonder why you have only this listing (in question it looks even cut too early).

---

C) the obvious option is to debug it on paper, it's so short, that with instruction reference guide you can easily look up any instruction and write notes next to the original lines, what you think is going on.

And A-hybrid) do it as part of C++ code, so you can call a real `atoi` and `rand` functions. These of course may be different from original, so it's still not clear how you want to get the exactly same results, as original code, when you don't have whole original code available.

From Peter's comment:
compiling a `.S` (extension for Assembly source files mostly used by GCC) with `gcc` will give you easy access to the real libc `atoi` and `rand` functions. GNU `as` (gas) doesn't even need EXTERN declarations.

Comment: You'll have a much easier time assembling it with gas, since it's using AT&T syntax.  i.e. put it in a `.S` file, and run gcc on it.  Edit the jump targets back into symbolic labels, like `call atoi`, and you're good to go.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks, I didn't actually read the code, so I missed the fact it is in AT&T. :) (I prefer to not see it anyway :) )

Comment: Haha, yeah I often don't spend much time trying to actually read the code on many of the low-quality asm questions either.  It's not fun reading most beginners' horrible code, which is why I'm pretty aggressive about downvoting questions that don't have good text descriptions of the problem and what they found with a debugger.  In this case, the formatting was very obviously `objdump` output, though, so I recognized it right away.

Comment: re: last paragraph: compiling a `.S` with gcc will give you easy access to the real libc `atoi` and `rand` functions.  GNU `as` doesn't even need EXTERN declarations.